# Installing rails and RVm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

newbee here. Hope you can help me with this.

**rails -v**

```
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:
    $ sudo gem install railsYou can then rerun your "rails" command.

KrisOrqla:~ Kris$ sudo gem install rails
Password:

Failed to load /Users/Kris/.gemrc because it doesn't contain valid YAML hash
Fetching: minitest-5.4.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed minitest-5.4.2
Fetching: tzinfo-1.2.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed tzinfo-1.2.2
Fetching: i18n-0.6.11.gem (100%)
Successfully installed i18n-0.6.11
Fetching: activesupport-4.1.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activesupport-4.1.6
Fetching: erubis-2.7.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed erubis-2.7.0
Fetching: builder-3.2.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed builder-3.2.2
Fetching: actionview-4.1.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed actionview-4.1.6
Fetching: rack-1.5.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rack-1.5.2
Fetching: rack-test-0.6.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rack-test-0.6.2
Fetching: actionpack-4.1.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed actionpack-4.1.6
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError)
    no such name (https://api.rubygems.org/gems/tilt-1.4.1.gem) ( ITS SAYS ERROR)
```

I type rails -v again but the problem occured!

Thanks

Comment: I tried but it's till not working. (Failed to load /Users/Kris/.gemrc because it doesn't contain valid YAML hash
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError)
    no such name (https://api.rubygems.org/gems/tilt-2.0.1.gem).Error seems to be about the valid YAML hash. What is this all about? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your rails gem not installed properly yet. While we install rails gem first all the dependency gems installed then rails install. Rails dependency gem `tilt` not installed properly here. try run `sudo gem install tilt -v='1.4.1'` separately then again run `sudo gem install rails`. then check `rails` gem present in your gem list.

Comment: If you are using ubuntu 12.04.  My blog here if you need any help on configuration on ruby on rails on ubuntu..

Comment: link here http://blog.grepruby.com/2014/09/configure-ubuntu-1204-for-ruby-on-rails_8.html

Comment: Hi Nitin, I am using mac. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

i already solved this problem. Ruby and Rails were successfully installed. I just followed these two for instructions. (http://installrails.com/steps/choose_os) and (http://docs.railsbridge.org/installfest/osx_rvm?back=macintosh%23step2-1)